# the device or resource (localhost) is not set up to accept connections on port "8000"

Tags: connection, localhost, firewall, localserver

I have installed phycharm and started the internal Django web server. However, I am not able to connect with the localhost server with 127.0.0.1:8000.

I get the following error upon troubleshooting:
the device or resource (localhost) is not set up to accept connections on port "8000"

When I ping 127.0.0.1 it responds and listens to the phyton.exe application. However, I am not able to open the localhost:8000 in my browser.

I have also tried the following to fix this:

1. Changed my host file setting by enabling 127.0.0.1 localhost
2. Changed the firewall settings by adding inbound and outbound rules for 8000 port.
3. Added the DNS server address in the network settings.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have a very similar issue, though mine works until I attempt to use /admin and then it fails to connect.

Comment: have you solved it by any chance?